# Starting an Action after another action's effect is finished dispatching its success action

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I need to display a list of all users in my application that are matching a certain set of filters. I am getting the filters via an http get call ("getClass"). When I get a response with the set of filter I have to make another http call to get the users that are matching those filters.

So I made an action called - GetClass and also made GetClassSuccess for the effect. 
I also have an action called - GetDirectory and a matching GetDirectorySuccess that the matching effect will dispatch.

Now here is my question:
if I write a sequence of commands:

```
this.store.dispatch(new directoryActions.GetClass());
this.store.dispatch(new directoryActions.GetDirectory());
```

The GetClass action triggers the GetClassSuccess action that updates the state with the correct filters. The GetDirectory action then takes those filters from the state (using withLatestFrom) and make an http request of getUsers. Then it triggers the GetDirectorySuccess which updates the state with the users that are matching the filters.

I can't guarantee that myClass will end by the time that GetDirectory will start. Infact it will never will.

So what is the best way to make sure and action has finished before starting another action. Should I make another effect that listens to the "GetClassSuccess" and then dispatched "GetDirectory" action?

Comment: You call GetClassSuccess within GetClass effect. You can also call GetDirectory in GetClassSuccess effect.

Comment: To refine @MoxxiManagarm's answer just a little, if there is ever a case where `GetClassSuccess` needs to *not* call `GetDirectory`, you can pass a boolean in the `GetClassSuccess` payload to tell it whether or not to dispatch `GetDirectory`.

Comment: GetClass success updates the state with the filters and then GetDirectory takes the filter from the state and brings the matching users.

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: Nope. I am using another effect. It seems to me that there must be a better solution buy maybe I'm wrong. But @WillAlexander and MoxxiManagarm's solution can help for some scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
@Effect()
login$: Observable <Action> = this
.actions$
.pipe(ofType<authAction.Login>(authAction.LoginActionTypes.LOGIN), mergeMap(action => this.authService.login(action.payload).pipe(
// If successful, dispatch success action with result
map(data => ({type: authAction.LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS})),
// If request fails, dispatch failed action
catchError(() => of({type: authAction.LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_FAIL})))));


@Effect({dispatch: false})
loginSuccess$ = this
.actions$
.pipe(ofType(authAction.LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS), tap(() => this.router.navigate(['/portal'])));
```

So you see that first effect return the type `LOGIN_SUCCESS`. Second Effect will listen on `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action and will execute second effect